# Copy/Pasting text reverse

Tags: copy-paste, arabic

Hey guys I have a problem with Arabic language.

For example I have a sentence like this in word doc ;

```
ios ننشأ مشروع جديد في نظام الـ
```

So I want to copy/paste it to a .txt file and when i do that,
It pastes this sentence like that to .txt;

```
ننشأ مشروع جديد في نظام الـios
```

Comment: it pastes fine to me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the text direction in the second one is not set 'right-to-left'. I'm not sure which text editor you're using, but in the Mac Text Edit it's Format -> Text -> Writing Direction -> Right to Left.

If you're not looking at it in a text editor, but instead are planning on using it in your web application, then don't worry about how it looks in the txt file. You'll be able to set the text direction when you output the data on your site.